# Binding expression results in error, but compiles/runs fine

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I seem to be getting an error when creating binding expressions in Android Studio. The code seems to compile and run ok and the method is called, but I'm still left with an error in Android Studio.

[image: Binding expression error]

Am I missing something here? As far as the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#method_references) is concerned I don't think I am.

Comment: I have seen that as well, and also in my case it runs fine. I didn't bother checking way lint is complaining about it tho.

Comment: Android Studio keeps improving its databinding support, so I'd update to the latest beta for best results. If that does not help, search bug reports or file a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio is following data binding implementation and may show warnings or errors where there is no problem. It should keep improving.